# How does one disable the media scanner? (obviously on a rooted device)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, boot, media-scanner

Running a rooted Galaxy S2 with DarkyROM2 2.3.5 & SuperCore kernel. I have a 32 GB microSD card in addition to the 16 GB internal storage, and it takes ages to scan both when the phone boots. At times when I connect USB mass storage mode and later turn off, it goes into an infinite reboot loop. Have tried [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.addz.mediascannerroot), but it doesn't appear to work. Any other workarounds?

Comment: Did you enable USB Debugging? The app just sends one system command so if it doesn't work I don't know if anything does (see the relevant [XDA Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=7646738)).

Comment: Yep,it's on, you can't use mass storage mode otherwise! That's the thread I originally got it from.

Comment: Is it possible to do it **without** rooting the device ?

Answer (score 0):

Via the command line:

```
$ su
# pm disable com.android.providers.media/com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerReceiver
```

Comment: Does this method require rooting the device ?

Comment: Yes. `su` is the super user command.

Comment: is it possible to do this without rooting the device?

Comment: `pm disable com.android.providers.media/.MediaScannerReceiver` is enough.